# Hyper-V inconsistent/high latency between two VMs on the same vSwitch

Tags: networking, hyper-v, ping, latency

This is a clean installation of Windows 10 1903 with Hyper-V, though I've experienced this in previous versions of Windows 10.

Add a private vSwitch (so, not tied to any physical network adapter). Install Linux on two VMs on the same server (tested with Ubuntu Server and CentOS). Configure static IPs on both VMs on the vSwitch interface.

Pings between the VMs are not consistent at all, and range from 0.2ms to ~4ms.

This isn't a huge deal, but I am looking to do some network benchmarking with software between the two VMs, so this inconsistency is worrying.

What could be causing this and how can I make this latency consistent? I don't have anything special yet, this just seems to be the default behavior with Hyper-V as far as I can tell. I would expect sub-1ms ping responses.

Edit: Disabling VMQ on the virtual NICs of both VMs doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try fastping (fping) or a tool that can do more accurate measurements. Then you can see if you have some kind of anomalies or spikes in the response time.

Comment: @Overmind fping still shows latencies all over the place between VMs using the -c flag. Over the course of 100 pings from A to B and B to A, latency ranges from 0.18 to 15.9 ms. Average is 1.86 ms on both, so that's something, but compared to sub-1ms on VirtualBox and VMware, this doesn't jive.